# Filtering image with fft

Tags: image, fft, convolution

I am trying to apply filter to image using 2D FFT. I have filter matrix (convolution kernel etc), but if I want to use fft I need to expand filter and picture matrix to power of 2 square matrix.

First I expand it with zeros (so matrix of picture and filter would be in top left corner of big power of 2 matrix) and I got this result

[image: Result with simple zero expanding]

Then I tried what I did with picture matrix when I was applying convolution without fft, padded picture matrix with filter dimension/2 from each side, and than that padded matrix with simple expand filter matrix to power of 2 matrix to convolve with fft and i got this
[image: with padded matrix]

This is original picture.

[image: original]

About algorithm:
I am applying 2d fft on both expanded matrixes and than dotwise multiply matrixes after what Im doing simple inverse fft. Also picture matrix are number from 0 to 16M (first 8 bits are red, second 8 bits are green and third 8 bits are blue)

I think that problem is in way how I am expanding picture and filter matrix to square power of 2 matrix but im not sure. I tested fft functions (fft and inverse fft, i got same picture (without dotwise multiplication))

Also filter is

```
 0 .2  0
.2 .2 .2
 0 .2  0
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to transform the image all at once.
Use FFTs on subblocks.  Overlap the transformed subimages by the kernel size and either discard the wraparound transient (overlap-save) or add the input-on and input-off transients (overlap-add).

Understand [fast convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Fast_convolution_algorithms) in one dimension before you try to do it in two.

Comment: Sorry I dont understand. What should be dimensions of subblocks? Also,  in transformation to subimages how i create wraparound transient? I know how to apply convolution without FFT but use of FFT confuses me lot.

Comment: FFTs accomplish circular convolution.  This is equivalent to linear (i.e. normal) convolution if the FFT length is larger than the sum of the two signals' lengths minus 1.

Comment: One other thing: the filter you give above is extremely small.  Using FFTs will likely be much slower than direct convolution.  Is that just a test filter for getting your code straight, or is that your real filter?

Comment: And also, can fft convolution work for matrix with even power of 2? I rewrite code so it would do fft for each channel separately and it works, but it work only for 2^n where n is odd number.

Comment: It should work with almost arbitrary FFT sizes.  Are you doing the entire image in one FFT?  Technically, that should work but it will be slower than needed and limit the size of image you can filter.

Comment: Probably I will use more FFTs (its school assignment and I should submit it in few days, so if I cannot solve why dont work for even powers of two, I have no other option). Can you tell me approximately where can be a problem for even powers? Also when I divide image into subimages, I use same filter matrix for all subimages?

Example: for image 1024x1024, I want to divide it in 512 block, I form filter like image is 512 and use same filter on all 4 blocks?