# Convolution with unpadded kernel

Tags: image-processing, kernel, filtering, mask

Suppose, I have an Image of size `512`x`256`. If I convert it into a 2D complex array to apply FFT, the size of the array would still be `512`x`256`. Now, if the size of my kernel is `10`x`10` and if I convert it to a 2D complex array, its size would still be `10`x`10`. Isn't that so?

If that is so, **Why don't we create a kernel of size `512`x`256` and convolve the image directly (rather than creating a kernel of size `10`x`10` and pad it)?**

Suppose, I have an Image of size of `512`x`256` pixels.

What would be the difference in the output if,

1. I prepare a kernel of size `512`x`256` and convolve the Image?
2. I prepare a kernel of size `256`x`256`, pad that to make it `512`x`256` and then convolve the Image?
3. I prepare a kernel of size `256`x`256`, pad that to make it of size `(512+256)` X `(256+256)`, pad the image to make it of the same size and then convolve them?

Comment: If you just pad the kernel with zeros there should be no difference whatsoever. So do not do that. But I am a bit worried that you think a image convolution kernel is related in size to the image to be processed. Usual kernels are quite small, like 10x10 or so. Are you talking about convolution using a matrix?

Comment: `But I am a bit worried that you think a image convolution kernel is related in size to the image to be processed.` --- Suppose, I have an Image of size `512`x`256`. If I convert that image into a 2D complex array to apply FFT, the size of the array would still be `512`x`256`. Now, if the size of my kernel is `10`x`10` and if I convert it to a 2D complex array, its size would still be `10`x`10`. Isn't that so? If that is so, how can I convolve them with each other? In that case, I suppose, I need to pad either the kernel or both. Am I correct?

Comment: Ah, sorry I was confused on terminology here. I have no useful help on fft based convolution. Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328502/filtering-image-with-fft

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On small kernel sizes (and especially in low dimensions) it can be more efficient to apply them "directly" without using FFT, but on larger problems utilizing the [Convolution Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem) is very beneficial. Also [FFTW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FFTW) has great performance on various hardware.

Naturally to do the point-wise multiplication your matrices must have identical shape. Thus `10 x 10` kernel is padded with zeros to get the desired size, FFT of the kernel and image are calculated, element-wise product is done and IFFT gets us the desired result.

I'm a bit puzzled about your kernel "preparation" process, not sure how "generating `512 x 256` kernel" is different from "generating `256 x 256` kernel and padding it".

But for example if you are using a Gaussian kernel with the "radius" of 150 pixels then you'd get boundary effects as it doesn't have enough "space" to decay down to approximately zero. On `512 x 256` kernel it would have enough horizontal space to decay to `exp(-((512 / 2) / 150)^2) = 0.0543...` but vertically it would be capped at `exp(-((256 / 2) / 150)^2) = 0.4827...`, significantly greater than zero.

Edit: Got home so could use Matlab to create an example image. This blur has a radius of 80 pixels but even that causes noticeable artifacts on FFT result of the padded kernel.

```
f = @(i) fftshift(mat2gray(log(1 + abs(fft2(i)))))
[x y] = meshgrid((1:512)-256, (1:256)-128); z = zeros(256, 128);
i1 = exp(-(x.^2+y.^2)/80^2); i2=[z i1(:,129:(256+128)) z];
imshow([i1 f(i1); i2 f(i2)], 'border', 'tight')
```

[image: FFT on kernel]

Answer (score 2):

> Suppose, I have an Image of size 512x256. If I convert it into a 2D complex array to apply FFT, the size of the array would still be 512x256. Now, if the size of my kernel is 10x10 and if I convert it to a 2D complex array, its size would still be 10x10. Isn't that so?

It depends on what you understand by *size*:

- If size is the conceptual dimension of the image, the answer is yes.
- If size is the space in memory, the answer is no.
- If you are talking about the mathematical dimension, the answer is no.

> If that is so, Why don't we create a kernel of size 512x256 and convolve the image directly (rather than creating a kernel of size 10x10 and pad it)?

**Kernel size:** A kernel is *small* by nature: "In image processing, a kernel, convolution matrix, or mask is a small matrix useful for blurring, sharpening, embossing, edge detection..." ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing))). The idea of the kernel is that you have a math operator that works locally on the image. This means that each pixel in the image is affected only by the surrounding pixels. The size of that neighborhood is the size of the kernel, in your case 10x10.

**Padding and convolution:** To apply the kernel to the image, there are two ways:

1. Direct convolution: Convolve the image with the kernel, both with its original size. You will get a (512 + 10 -1) x (256 + 10 -1) image, that you have to crop to keep the size.
2. Convolution via FFT: Compute the FFT of the image (512x256 complex matrix); compute the FFT of the padded kernel (512x256 complex matrix); multiply element by element both matrices, finally compute the IFFT of the result to get the convolution.

Doing the convolution via FFT is computationally more efficient.

> What would be the difference in the output if,
>
> 1. I prepare a kernel of size 512x256 and convolve the Image?
> 2. I prepare a kernel of size 256x256, pad that to make it 512x256 and then convolve the Image?
> 3. I prepare a kernel of size 256x256, pad that to make it of size (512+256) X (256+256), pad the image to make it of the same size and then convolve them?

All three options are probably not what you want. You want to keep the kernel small (10x10). You only pad it if you are doing the convolution via FFT.

I suggest to use the direct convolution method first with your original 10x10 kernel. Examine the resulting image and check if it is what you expected.
If you then want to optimize execution time, use the FFT method.